# How to add quantity field on woo commerce archive page on which when i add or subtract product it automatically update cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, archive

i am trying to add quantity fields on woo commerce archive page i add them with this filter

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        // Get the necessary classes
        $class = implode( ' ', array_filter( array(
            'button',
            'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
            $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
        ) ) );

        // Adding embeding  tag and the quantity field
        $html = sprintf( '%s%s%s%s',
            '',
            woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false ),
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ),
            ''
        );
    }
    return $html;
}
```

```
add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'archives_quantity_fields_script' );
function archives_quantity_fields_script(){
    if( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ): ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function($){
            // Update quantity on 'a.button' in 'data-quantity' attribute (for ajax)
            $('form.cart').on('change', 'input.qty', function() {
                if ($(this).val() === '0') 
                    $(this).val('1');
                $(this).closest('form.cart').find( 'a.add_to_cart_button').attr('data-quantity', $(this).val());
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php endif;
}
```

but what i really need to do is that i want when someone click on + button it automatically add product to cart and if click on - button product remove from cart please help me to do that if someone know how to do this
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done already? Share some code and explain your efforts.

Comment: I add action mansion above and this add quantity fields on my archive page now i need that when i click on them cart or mini cart price automatically update + and - buttons works but price very when i click add to cart button i want that without add to cart button